# Identify the strings in python array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a data similar to,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [['1','2','3'], ['a','3','5']] )
```

Now I want to identify the cell address of `'a'`. I have tried the following code for that purpose,

```
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if (type(float(A[i,j])) == float):
            print(str(i)+str(j))
```

since, `'a'` can't be converted into floating point it shows the following error.

> 00
>
> 01
>
> 02
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in
>
> `if (type(float(A[i,j])) == float):`
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to use `A[i][j]` or is that some fancy `numpy` magic?

Comment: Your data is going to be just one character? Then you could use `isdigit` and so https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: @SumnerEvans the `__getitem__` of `numpy` arrays accepts tuples!

Comment: *everything* is a string in your array. Why are you even using `numpy` here?

Comment: @timgeb, that's cool! I've never used numpy before, so that's really neat.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think OP is trying to differentiate between things that can and cannot be coerced to numbers. I also don't really see why it matters what they are using numpy for

Comment: Try `np.where(A == 'a')`.

Comment: You can check the type of variable with `isinstance(A[i,j], float)`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak right, well, my point is that the OP should be *precise*, since taken at face value, that is not what they are asking. I made the comment about `numpy` because this doesn't seem like a good use case for `numpy`, i.e. the use of strings.

Comment: @Alexey that will always be `False` in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
import numpy as np

def is_number(s):
   try:
    int(s)
    return True
   except ValueError:
    return False

A = np.array( [['1','2','3'], ['a','3','5']] )

for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if not is_number(A[i][j]):
            print i , j
```